# angular redirect to route + cache

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have a login form at my homepage. When an user submit form angular send post request to `auth/login` *(laravel's default auth system -> it doesn't matter)*. It logs the user but then I want to refresh homepage view. I tried this:

```
$http({
  data: {},
  method: 'POST',
  ..
}).success(function(data) {
  ..
  $templateCache.remove('/');
  $location.path('/');
});
```

But it's not working. In console I see new request at homepage, but it doesn't change any data(when the user logs in he can see his nick instead of login form).

Where can be problem? (maybe problem can be that I'm changing location to the current? when I set `$location.path('/something-else')` it works).

Answer (score 0):

I thought it's possible to remove 1 certain template from cache, but it's. You can only remove all templates with `$templateCache.removeAll();`